# Is it a good idea to invest in a small-scale solar power plant for income?

Tags: greece, electricity, investment-income

Right now I have a good income from my software engineering job and want to supplement that with a small solar power plant (costing between 5000€ - 7000€) and sell power to the grid.

I would be happy if I could earn 300 - 500€ per month (which is a typical wage in Greece, but way less than my current income). AFAIK a typical ROI is in 5 years on a typical solar power plant.

Do you think it is a good idea to use this approach, so I can have an income not based upon software engineering?

My idea is to have small steady income from selling electricity, so I can use this income to fund a future software project I want to start.

Though my plan may have some drawbacks:

1. Maintenance: Usually how much is the maintenance cost for a solar power unit?
2. ROI: Does a typical solar power plant take 5 years to pay for itself?

The unit will be installed in Greece.

Comment: How much income do you expect to generate with your power plant?

Comment: How sensitive is the cost of electricity?  In the future, you may generate very little income because the price of power is low.

Comment: It is impossible to provide a 'good idea' / 'bad idea' answer to this question without actually knowing what the expected revenue is. You will need to do local research on that based on typical energy production from a similar solar panel + price of selling back energy to your utility company. In some areas, lack of sun or lack of good utility regulation can make solar panels almost worthless.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon where I can find this information you need? Usually this is not a free information and Idk the correct keywords.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas This isn't a solar power Q&A site, so determining how much power you should expect to produce, what it would cost to install, etc., is not really on topic here. Start by contacting local solar power installation companies near you and begin getting quotes from them on installation, and ask for information they have on what you can expect to produce. You will want to verify they are being honest by then researching online the claims they make.

Comment: I don't follow your math. "small solar power plant (costing between 5000€ - 7000€)" and "typical ROI is in 5yrs" does not yield "300 - 500€ per month". At 300/mo over 5 years that would be 18,000 in revenue. Is your initial cost missing a 0 and should be 50,000 - 70,000?

Comment: Dimitrios, I have a bad feeling your calculations are way way out?  There is no chance you can earn even 10 or 20 euros a month, selling that small amount of electricity, I am afraid to say :O

Comment: @Fattie That was what I would desire without any sort of calculations. And of course are way out. That's why I am still investigating it.

Comment: What do you mean by "a typical ROI is in 5 years on a typical solar power plant"?

Comment: I mean this is what I heard and I am not sure if this is true.

Comment: I interpreted the question as saying "earn 300 - 500€ per month *with all of my investments combined*" rather than "earn 300 - 500€ per month *with a single power plant*." Am I interpreting that correctly?

Comment: Well the power plant will be my own investment.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas I added a starting point for research to my answer - looks like earning 300 EUR / month might be possible for a very large installation, but I couldn't immediately see any quotes, you will probably have better luck just calling actual local installers in your area for that [your local language is 'all Greek to me!']. Good luck, looks like you might get what you're looking for!

Comment: hi @DimitriosDesyllas , unfortunately I do have to say, your figures are "incredibly" out.  You would be lucky to make *one hundred euros in a year* selling the electricity from the unit you mention.  I'm sorry to say.

Comment: I don't think these nr. are right. Either multiply by 10 the cost or divide by 10 the ROI. Even then, it still appears too optimistic. Is the source a seller of power plants? Normally you amortize your investment in 15-20 years.

Comment: I had a £5k solar installation five years ago in the UK and it makes about £500 a year (not month) *in subsidies*. Those subsidies are no longer available to new installations here, and it looks like they aren't in Greece either.

Comment: @pjc50: it would be interesting to know how much you £5k installation made in revenue,  how much maintenance, and so on.

Comment: @QuoraFeans Maintenance is zero. Actual income is hard to work out because it's not net metered but on feed-in-tarriff, so I get a cheque for 13p/kWh generated regardless of whether I use or export or what the market price is.

Comment: I did however manage to graph the generation over a year. It's very seasonal at this latitude: https://flatline.org.uk/daystats.html

Comment: This is a very interesting question because it brings up something I'm not sure any utility providers near me offer - the ability to buy solar panels and sell ALL their power output into the grid.

Comment: As a side option, at least in my area, there are companies you can rent your roof for solar panel use. The roof is yours the pannels are theirs. All risc, research and headache stays with the company, you just get steady predefined rent. I would at least check what the rates are for your area to estimate how profitable panels can be there.

Comment: Check your property is in a suitable position first. Do you get direct sunlight during the middle of the day, or is it in shadow? If you plan on putting them on the roof, is it flat or sloped, and if it is sloped does one of the sides face roughly south? And if you aren't using solar hot water yet and have an electric boiler, install that first, it's more efficient and you'll save more money in somewhere like Greece.

Comment: @pjc50 sorry I have to ask, you really generated 27kWh on a day in June?  That seems impressive.

Comment: @JimWsaysreinstateMonica 27/3.85kw system = 7 full hours, on a day which was 14 hours from dawn till dusk, near the solstice. Not that unreasonable.

Answer (score 24):

Whether any investment makes good financial sense depends on a few factors - let's see how this project lines up:

(1) **What are the projected revenues from the investment?**

- Looks like you have an expectation of how much this will earn you. Is that based on an actual scientific assessment of how much sunlight would hit your proposed installation area? Make sure you aren't simply assuming the energy output based on, for example, a salesperson telling you what to expect.
- Do you have actual contracted rates to sell back to your local utility company? This is going to be very jurisdiction dependent. Best case scenario would be a guarantee to buy back electricity at the same cost to use it [meaning they can't undercut what they would pay you compared to what they charge a regular customer].

(2) **What are the projected expenses to cover the investment?**

- Installation you have listed as 5-7k, but does that include the land needed to install it? Perhaps you are installing this on the roof of your house - is that the best way to get sunlight based on direction you face? Is it legal in your municipality to have a structure added like that? Are there permits you might need to buy? Would you need to re-shingle your roof in anticipation of having these installed?
- Maintenance will be the big question - do you have assurance over what long-term maintenance will cost? [especially - has this company / technology been around long enough to even know that?]

(3) **What are the risks / how likely is your projected outcome?**

- If you can't get any firm answers on some of the above, then what is the likelihood you are correct? If your revenues are not so guaranteed, you should consider reducing the projected impact of having them.
- In a 'worst case scenario' where for whatever reason you are unable to sell the power back to the grid, would this produce more power than you need personally? Would you need to buy some large batteries to store energy, and how long would it take to pay off that additional cost?

(4) **What is the 'opportunity cost' of spending that money initially?**

- You could take that same 5k and invest it, maybe even buying shares in a diversified renewable energy company. Perhaps that has a lower risk, or a higher risk, and a lower return, or a higher return, than doing it yourself. But it would be less of a headache, too.
- You could also use that 5k for 'regular' investing, in a diversified index fund or similar, and earn something that way.
- The point is that if you project that your solar panels would earn you, say, 5% a year, and the stock market could earn you, say, 7% a year, you need to consider if this is higher risk than the stock market.
- In your case, since you plan on doing a software engineering project 'down the road', installing this solar project would cost you 5k that you could even just use to immediately start funding your project.

And, specifically for something like renewable energy:
(5) **Are there any government incentives / restrictions to consider?**

- It is quite possible your government could give you some type of tax credit for installing renewable energy equipment. That could be a big impact to the profitability of the idea.

At the end of all the above, from a strictly financial perspective, the simplest mechanical way to figure out the $ impact would be: how many years until the investment pays for itself. My understanding of solar projects is that majority of the cost is simply installation, and they can be mostly self-sufficient as long as: (a) little snowfall occurs in your area; and (b) you can very easily sell energy back to the utility grid without negotiating.

**In short, how much energy do you expect to produce, what is the price to sell it back to the grid, and therefore how much do you expect to earn per year?** Once you know the annual earnings of the investment, consider how many years it would take to pay for itself, and how many years you should expect the panels to last. If it pays for itself in 5 years, and lasts 20 years, for example, that would be one way to see this as valuable investment.

**Edit because this has hit Hot, I've done a bit of digging and thrown in some more specific numbers**:

I'm relying on a couple of external sources for the following data, see here:
http://www.schellas.gr/en/categories.asp?catid=90
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261366438_Cost_of_PV_electricity_-_Case_study_of_Greece

In short, it looks like you might be able to get 40MWh of power annually from a very large rooftop installation , like over 800 sq ft [hard to tell exactly because technology has advanced a lot over the past 10 years, so old figures of output may be outdated], unsure of the cost of that installation. Looks like you can sell back to PPC at a cost of about 80 Eur / Mwh, so maybe as much as 3,200 EUR per year, or about 260 EUR per month. Looks like your initial estimate of earning about 300 Eur per month might be possible, and if you could get that installed for 7,000 EUR, it would pay for itself in about 2-3 years.

**So at a first pass of reasonability, looks like payoff in 5 years could be possible, assuming you are roughly in the ballpark for installation costs, and have a large enough roof**. You will note that this is heavily dependent on technology efficiency and government support for electricity buyback. If the government further promotes the idea great, but if they remove support you might no longer get the return you desire. **Definitely looks worth it to investigate further!**

Comment: There’s no way you’ll get a 20kW installation for anything like €7,000. You might just about be be able to buy 20kW of cheap panels for that price, leaving nothing for an inverter or installation.

Comment: Sure, but you could double the cost to 15k and, assuming you're able to produce 40MwH of power over a year at a price of 80 EUR / MwH, it could still pay off within 5 years. There is some breathing room for a 5 year payoff to still be possible. More local research would be needed to confirm it, and OP is going to need to do that themself.

Comment: I believe Mike is correct here, the numbers are totally off by two? orders of magnitude.  I believe.

Comment: Regarding the 5 excellent points, is it worth adding (6) Is there any capital recovery possibilities? Statistically all businesses fail, and it's ideal if there's some equipment or other capital that can be sold to recover some cash when it fails.

Comment: @Fattie It’s not as bad as two orders of magnitude. A 40kW installation won’t cost you $700,000. Might be close to one order of magnitude, without government subsidies.

Comment: @MikeScott - gotchya.  Looking at "how much you can make" of course it depends wildly on local government. But here's a completely random article about a European country where the bottom line is with a typical house installation you can make about £53 a year. https://www.theguardian.com/money/2019/jun/30/solar-panels-smart-export-guarantee-is-it-still-worth-it  Maybe the info will help our OP.  (The article also has a chilling reminder that solar panels, like Tesla batteries ......... wear out.)

Comment: @Fattie Keep in mind [and I'm no expert on solar by any means] Greece [2,771 average sunny hours / year] is going to be a far more profitable place to run solar than the UK [1,354 average sunny hours / year].

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Yes, that’s why you can get 40MWh from a 20kW installation instead of the 40kW it would need in the UK.

Comment: The very largest utility scale solar installations are going in at under $1 per Watt. So the absolute floor of the cost of this hypothetical system is $20k = 17k EUR. Realistically, OP has neither the bargaining power nor the economies of scale to get it down that low.

Comment: And let's not forget about insurance costs. Otherwise the first hailstorm could destroy that solar panel and you remain with nothing.

Comment: Another issue to consider, can you actually feed all produced power back? If everyone in the neighborhood has solar panels, there is more electricity produced than consumed, and any excess energy gets turned into heat at the solar panels, instead of money. This is more likely to happen on sunny days

Comment: It might be a good idea to also factor in [the cost of recycling the solar panels](https://www.wired.com/story/solar-panels-are-starting-to-die-leaving-behind-toxic-trash/) at the end of their lifespan (about 25 years down the road).

Comment: @Ferrybig: True, especially for Greek islands. I understand only some of them are connected to the national grid. On the smaller islands, either the whole island will be in the sun (no demand, no revenue) or the whole island will be under a cloud (no supply, no revenue either).

Answer (score 21):

As usual, Bacon's answer is excellent. I'd like to direct some feedback to the data you specifically provided.

Your anticipated cost of the solar power system is 5000€ - 7000€ and you expect to earn 300€ - 500€ per month. If that was a legitimate expectation, I believe everyone would go and make the same investment and Greece would have more solar panels than square meters to place them. Sign me up!

I don't know the power and solar markets in Greece, but I can't imagine it's so drastically different than the US that you would be able to earn that kind of monthly income compared to such a low up-front cost. In the US, the average cost for a 6kW solar system is [somewhere around $15500](https://www.solarreviews.com/solar-panel-cost/), or 13000€. This is enough to cover the power needs of an average home and maybe put a small amount back into the grid. US power companies rarely offer to pay cash out for what you put back in, but will give credits to your account so when you don't produce enough to cover the home, you might not go out of pocket. Let's call the average monthly power cost $200 when looking at a whole year, that means we would need to go up to a 15+kW system to generate the lowest end of the monthly earnings you suggest. (Apologies, I don't know the power measurement conversions to provide an equivalent system size for Greece.)

Comment: Though I will use the solar panel for just selling it without consuming the power I produce.

Comment: One point to add - I think most of the US is one of the jurisdictions where there is not a government mandate to allow consumers to sell power back to utility companies at equal cost. In jurisdictions where that is possible, solar panels can make a lot more sense, because you don't need to buy the (very expensive) battery to store it for personal use. Not sure on the situation in Greece, or what the power costs are there.

Comment: I think you're being ripped off in the US if a 6kW system costs $15500.  We would pay about half that here in the UK.

Comment: Yes, US costs are about double. We have too many inspection regulations and permitting costs. The hardware costs are competitive, it's the red tape that's expensive.

Comment: Most owners of small-scale solar project consume as much of their own power as they can. When they buy a kWh from their electric utility, they pay retail rates. But when they sell a kWh to an electric utility (assuming they can find one to even buy the kWh without being a customer) they only get paid the wholesale rate.

Comment: @stannius In Canada as an example, power is sold back to the utility company at retail rates. As mentioned previously, this is a very jurisdiction-dependent question.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon in jurisdictions with mandated net metering, customers "sell" their excess electricity back to the utility at retail rates, and then later "buy" electricity at retail rates. However, you still have to be a customer of the utility, and usually you can only "sell" as much as you "buy" in a given period (sometimes a billing period, sometimes a year, sometimes you can bank indefinitely but you can only use the bank credits to buy electricity, you can't get it paid out in cash).

Comment: I am not aware of any jurisdiction that forces utilities to buy electricity at retail rates from any random third-party entity who wants to sell it. Even if such a mandate exists somewhere, I would bet it is likely to be rescinded sooner or later, otherwise as panel prices go down, utilities would sooner or later be forced to buy more electricity than they can sell at buy prices higher than what they can sell it for.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas - You would sell without consuming? Are you able to sell for higher than what you would pay? Otherwise, that seems illogical. It would make far more sense to boost your earnings by lowering your monthly expenses rather than sell the electricity for less than you have to pay for it. Again, I have 0 knowledge about Greece's power costs and infrastructure. Please let me know if I'm way off the mark!

Comment: "In the US, the average cost for a 6kW solar system is somewhere around $15500" - That seems excessive.  Or at least, in Australia you can get a 6.6kW system supplied and installed for around AU$3000 (US$2200).  Granted that's after assigning your STCs to the installer.  However those are only worth around AU$3000 on a 6.6kW system, not AU$10k plus.  Call it AU$6500 with the incentives taken off the table, and US$15k still looks extortionate.  Someone over there is raking in the profits.

Comment: @aroth - I was excluding tax credits from the equation because (in the US) that value is dependent on other things and isn't a guaranteed amount. If you get a quote from an installation company, they might say "$6,000!" but be including tax credits in that amount. The US is far behind many other countries on adoption of solar with regards to making it more affordable.

Comment: A 6 kWp system only leaving "a little bit" to feed back to the grid might also be dependent on the common usage for your locale. - For Germany, I'd expect a 3 kWp system to be sufficient to produce enough electricity for a one family home to have a balanced input/output. Greece will have somewhat lower efficiency (due to higher temperatures), but maybe twice as many hours of sunshine. - If you calculate 6 kW, are you also heating/cooling the dwelling with that?

Comment: @BobbyScon Yes I would be selling without consumming. Also I was thinkinh small as an experiment without breaking the bank.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas You'll make more money by consuming rather than selling, almost certainly.  Displace your own consupmtion first, then sell the excess back to the grid.  Unless you plan to install this somewhere other than your home?  On land you own?  Or are planning to pay rent for?

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas Also, a "small" investment in the energy industry is a contradiction in terms.  This is an industry with very thin margins.  That means to make money you need to spend money, and LOTS of it.  Not breaking the bank is not really an option.  The bigger you are and the more you spend the more you can gain efficiency and margin.  You cannot make profits in the energy industry when you're a tiny installation.

Comment: @J... the trick with eating your own dogfood is "the time when solar is making power, is NOT the same time as you want to use power".  You're at work. Nothing's turned on in your house except the internet router.  So you need to sell this moment's power to someone who needs it (industry, people with air conditioners, pumped storage) and then draw back off the grid when you're cooking at sunrise or sunset, or washing clothes after dark.

Comment: Also about the margins of the energy industry... solar power *mostly* is available during system peaks, when power is worth the most.  You're not competing with a baseline coal plant, you're competing with a turbine peaking unit.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yes, I understand how it works.  I hear "selling only" to mean an islanded generating installation separate from a household.  By "consuming" I mean grid-connected behind the household meter.  For 5k euro you'll get something that will maybe offset a typical household, so the net effect is OP has a near net-zero utility bill.  Hardly the money making venture they were hoping for.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The major draw on peak is HVAC/cooling anyway (when spot prices are driving higher), and a house needs that to some degree or another whether it is occupied or not.

Comment: @J... I'm intrigued by the idea of selling without consuming mainly because my power company tells me that it would cost MORE to go solar, mainly because of their stupid convoluted pricing scheme.

Comment: @Michael I suspect the answer is probably in the details of that convoluted pricing scheme.

Comment: @J... To be fair that was based on a 4 year old assessment, so I thought I would re-run it.  Apparently for a cash outlay of $16,500 (after tax credits) I would save around $15,000 over the life of the panels (given as 20 years), on the best possible pricing scheme for my historical usage.  Worse of course for financing it. I was too disgusted to dig into the pricing scheme to find out why but I suspect you are right.

Comment: @J... I've never lived in a house that had a powered cooling system when not occupied.  And rarely when occupied.  I'm not sure what kind of person thinks everyone needs A/C all summer, but my guess would be "Arizonan" :)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica It's pretty ubiquitous here in Canada.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica And I just looked it up - nearly all greek households have A/C.  Seems reasonable given the climate.

Comment: @aroth it's complicated. But on the pure cost side, you can also get them for free in the US, depending what you buy and how you contract for it.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas - You'll pretty much always come out better if you consume your own solar power and only sell the excess, since the price for selling power is never higher than the price for buying it.  If that were not true, you could sell the power company's own power back to them at a profit.

Answer (score 12):

Another aspect that hasn't been mentioned so far, is that the low voltage system in Greece is not capable of maintaining stability while handling energy injections by distributed generation at arbitrary connecting points, and it is currently under stress from the existing installations.

Thus, unless OP is lucky and his land is at a favourable location, the distribution system operator is unlikely to accept to connect to the new installation.

Here is the current availability map, where green is where there is capacity for further absorption:

[image]

Sources:

1. https://apps.deddie.gr/WebAPE/main.html#
2. https://apps.deddie.gr/WebAPE/map.html

Comment: One alternative way to make money in such an environment is not to add to the peaky and oversaturated solar generation, but instead to invest in grid storage.  Where solar is over provisioned the issue is that the grid can end up with too much energy and not enough consumers.  Grid storage is one way to profit from this situation since it allows you to buy up power cheaply any time there is excess and to sell it back to the grid later when it is needed.

Comment: @J... That's very true. Storage, though costly, by and large solves the problem of uncontrollability of the generation. The problem of injecting into the system is not completely solved though, as the direction of the power flow affects the voltage and phase shift on the entire branch, so there is still a limit on the power you can inject without negatively affecting the grid, especially when the situation is near capacity and with limited measurement points.

Comment: @user000001 Yes, but it's a solved problem, and all of those questions have to be answered when you go through the planning process for grid connection.  Nothing gets approved without the utility operator saying OK, so you usually have to plan and locate carefully to ensure that your installation and the grid can mutually accommodate each other.  In any case, the situation is easy for grid storage because you're adding capacity when the grid needs it most and shaving excess production when the grid needs it gone.

Answer (score 9):

> Do you think it is a good idea to use this approach, so I can have an income not based upon software engineering?

If you think you are better at running a solar plant than you are at being a software engineer, yes.

If you're really good at being a software engineer but have no idea how to run a solar plant, no.

We have no idea what your competencies are, but your expectations for profit margin tell us that perhaps solar energy is not a particular area of expertise for you. Given that you don't seem to have a plan for how much power or money you require to meet your objectives, what your operating costs would be, etc, we can also conclude that running a business is also not a particular field of expertise for you.

5000 euro might buy you enough solar panels to make electricity for your own personal use, or perhaps a household of two.  There would be little, if any, left over to sell back to the grid.  At best you would be able to offset your monthly cost of electricity and perhaps make a small amount back.

The energy sector is one with very thin margins for profit.  If you intend to make income, you need to spend more money.  Much more.  Only with scale and efficiencies of size can you bring your costs down enough to be competitive.  You can't dabble in the energy industry — small fish do not survive.

I'd stick with software engineering.

With that said, investing in domestic renewable power like solar really can be a great idea, so all this is not to say that you should not consider adding solar generation to your home, I just wouldn't look at it as a money making venture.  It would help offset your energy costs long-term and is an environmentally conscious move to make.  It can end up generating a small profit, but nowhere near 300-500€/month.

If you were looking to make significant income from such a project you would be really considering at least 1€ million and up for outlay, and you would need a suitable piece of land to install the number of panels it would take.  Maybe with a small piece of land somewhere you could start something smaller, but just to pay the maintenance and carrying costs you will need at least a certain number of panels to provide that income - and you still want to make profit.  Whatever the case, it would be a much larger investment than 5k euro.

Comment: This answer wrongly assumes that investing in the solar panels comes at the opportunity cost of doing more software development. This would work if e.g. you were choosing between X or Y career. In this case however the solar panel represents a *passive income* source from investment, and whether OP is good or bad at software engineering is completely irrelevant. The choice to invest should be made on its own merits and compared against the actual opportunity cost (e.g. investing the money in stocks etc.) OP isn't quitting software development in order to make the investment.

Comment: @JBentley A solar farm is not like a security - it requires ongoing maintenance, service, and upkeep.  Planning and installing such a facility requires a well considered business plan, it requires investment capital, and it requires ongoing operational costs.  It is very much an opportunity cost consideration because OP must invest considerable effort in bringing this project to life.  The only way to make it fully hands-off would be to also outsource management and construction - this increases the cost and required scale of project to maintain profitability.  It's out of OP's depth.

Comment: We're not talking about a solar farm here. OP wants to invest 5000€ - 7000€ i.e. in the ballpark of a home/roof installation. The management time at this scale is not going to make any kind of noticeable impact on OP's ability to do his day job.

Comment: @JBentley OP wants to make 500EUR/month profit.  They think that investing 5k in solar will achieve this - it will not.  The point of this answer is to give a better idea of what size that investment *would have to look like* before OP could start making profits in that range.  A home installation will not impact OP's ability to do their day job.  It will also not provide them any income.  An installation that would provide them income would require more work, planning, and the execution of a considered business plan.

Comment: I agree. Hence why I said the choice to invest should be made on its own merits, not the opportunity cost. As you have pointed out, in this case there is no merit to the investment (or at least not as far as OP's expectations are concerned).

Comment: @JBentley I agree also, if the sole input is 5k to invest.  In this case it is not.  There is also a desire to make a certain benchmark profit.  The question here isn't *"what should I do with 5k to invest?"*, the question is *"can I make income from solar power?"*.  The latter requires that OP invest some of their time and effort, the former does not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113117/discussion-between-jbentley-and-j).

Answer (score 2):

Projections are uncertain. Especially when concerning the future. There is no guarantee that the grid owners will pay you in 2 years what they pay now. Many people have the same idea and revenue will drop below profitability. If you do it, do it because you like to provide some 'green' electricity for the sake of doing it. Don't do it if you want to make money.
For example, 20 years ago they promised a 4%/year gain in pension funds, now we are at 0.2%/year.

Comment: It´s a pretty save bet that the price of energy will go up when you consider Europe still claims to be committed to the Paris agreement ...